# Why does this integral rearrangement hold?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

A solution to one of my practice problems involves this:

$\int^\infty_0  \{\int^x_0 dy\}f(x)dx = \int^\infty_0  \{\int^\infty_y f(x) dx\}dy $

Where f() is a PDF function of a continuous random variable(if that makes any difference).

Why does this work? And what should I know in order to be able to apply this kind of step to problems in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an application of [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) and the observation that the domain of integration is $\{(x,y) \mid 0 \le y \le x < \infty\}$ which can be written in two ways. You can apply Fubini here as your function is non-negative and for seeing the two ways it sometimes helps mwe to write the bounded integral as in integral over a characteristic function as follows ($\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$, $0$ else):
\begin{align*}
   \int_0^\infty \int_0^x f(x)\,dy\,dx
   &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \chi_{[0,x]}(y)f(x)\, dy\,dx\\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \chi_{[0,x]}(y)f(x)\,dx\,dy\\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \chi_{[y,\infty)}(x)f(x)\,dx \,dy\\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \int_y^\infty f(x)\,dx\,dy
\end{align*}

Comment: So why does $\chi_{[0,x]}$ become $\chi_{[y,\infty]}$ ?

Comment: $\chi_{[0,x]}(y) = 1$ iff $y \in [0,x]$ iff $x \in [y,\infty)$ iff $\chi_{[y,\infty)}(x) = 1$.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. Thanks a lot for all the help :)