# Verify measurability hypothesis when applying Tonelli-Hobson test

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I’m trying to get that $E[T] = \int_0^\infty(S(t))$ where $T$ is a positive continuous random variable and $S(t) = P(T \geq t)$. After some research ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/642027/592777) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145382/592777)), I know it is possible to proceed this way:

\begin{align*}
   E[T] = \int_0^\infty tf(t) dt &= \int_0^\infty \bigg(\int_0^tdu\bigg) f(t)\,dt \\\
   &= \int_0^\infty \bigg(\int_u^\infty f(t)\,dt\bigg) du\\\
   &= \int_0^\infty P(T \geq u)\,du\\\
   &= \int_0^\infty S(t)\,du
\end{align*}

Where, for justifying the third equality, we can use first [Tonelli-Hobson test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Hobson_test) and then Fubini’s theorem. My doubts are related to the Tonelli-Hobson part. As I understand, the result must by applied to the function $g(t, u) = f(t)$ with domain $\{(t,u) : 0 \leq u \leq t\}$. We know that $\int_0^\infty \big(\int_0^t |g(t,u)| du\big) dt$ is finite because it is equal to $E[T]$, and this is supposed to exist. However, $g$ must be also measurable in order to verify all the hypothesis of the test.
How can I prove that it is measurable? Obviously, $f(t)\chi_{[0, \infty]}$ is integrable, can I proceed from this?

Comment: Not quite, Tonelli or Fubini's theorems apply for functions with "rectangular" domains. So you really are considering $g(t,u) = f(t) \mathbf{1}_\mathrm{D}(t,u)$ where $\mathrm{D}$ is the domain you wrote, but $(t,u)$ are elements of $[0, \infty) \times [0,\infty).$ Note measurability of $g$ follows immediately from those of $f$ and $\mathrm{D}.$

Comment: Could you be more specific, please, @WilliamM? I see that $D$ is measurable, but I don’t see how $f$ is measurable in $[0, \infty) \times [0, \infty)$, or how to use its measurability in one dimension to prove that.

Comment: Let $h(t,u) = f(t).$ Then $\{h < c\} = \{f < c\} \times [0, \infty)$ is a measurable set.

Comment: Are you using that the cartesian product of two measurable sets is measurable or other result? @WilliamM.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much @WilliamM. for your help! By the way, do you know any reference which includes the result about the cartesian product of two measurable sets?

Comment: In case anyone has the same doubt, [here](https://math.solverer.com/library/terence_tao/an_introduction_to_measure_theory/exercise_1-2-22) you can find a reference. Information taken from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566048/on-the-lebesgue-measure-of-a-cartesian-product). Thanks again @WilliamM.!!